# Trouble Achieving Optimal Parameters for XGBoost Regressor with Sin(x) Time Series

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, boosting

I'm facing a challenge while attempting to optimize parameters for an XGBoost regressor (Python) using time series data. I've created a time series using the following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    start_date = '2010-01-01'
    end_date = '2020-01-01'
    dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
    unix_dates = np.array([int(pd.Timestamp(d).timestamp()) for d in dates])
    freq = 'D'  # Monthly frequency
    date_rng = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq=freq)
    prices = np.sin(unix_dates)
    data = pd.DataFrame({'ds': date_rng, 'y': prices})
```

Now, I am attempting to train an XGBoost regressor using the following parameter combinations:

```
'max_depth': (3, 6, 12),
'learning_rate': (0.001, 0.01, 0.3),
'n_estimators': (1, 10, 50, 500)
```

For parameter tuning, I've considered both MSE and MAPE. However, I'm encountering two distinct issues based on the data shuffle:

**Constant Output**: When I don't shuffle my data, the XGBoost regressor produces a constant output.

**Noisy Output**: Conversely, when I shuffle my data, the model generates noisy predictions.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to effectively optimize the XGBoost regressor parameters for my time series data. Specifically, I'm seeking guidance on how to overcome the challenges related to the model's behavior with and without data shuffling.

Comment: What are you feeding xgboost? Just the y or other variables as well?

Comment: @Tyller I submit date as x and data as y

Answer (score 0):

With shuffling, I get a MAE of about 0.06:

[image]

Without shuffling, it's about 10 times worse, resulting in a bad fit. I think this is because your features (date) are linearly increasing, meaning that each split will have very different statistics, rather than the splits exhibiting similar statistics. Shuffling is necessary in this case to make the statistics of each split more similar.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV, KFold
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2020-01-01'
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
unix_dates = np.array([int(pd.Timestamp(d).timestamp()) for d in dates])
freq = 'D'  # Monthly frequency
date_rng = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq=freq)
prices = np.sin(unix_dates)
data = pd.DataFrame({'ds': date_rng, 'y': prices})

params = {
    'max_depth': [3, 6, 12],
    'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.3],
    'n_estimators': [1, 10, 50, 500],
}

model = XGBRegressor(random_state=0)
model.get_params()

#Prepare data for algorithm by
# converting datetime to a numeric format
X = data[['ds']].values.astype(np.int64)
y = data.y.values

search = GridSearchCV(
    model,
    params,
    n_jobs=-1,
    cv=KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=0), #with shuffling
    return_train_score=True,
    scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',
    verbose=0,
).fit(X, y)

cv_results = search.cv_results_

#View the CV results (sorted by test_score)
results_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(cv_results)
    .eval('mean_test_score = -mean_test_score')
    .sort_values('mean_test_score')
)
display(results_df.head(3))

#Get prediction using the best estimator
predictions = search.best_estimator_.predict(X)

#View the first 100 samples
plt.plot(y[:200], linewidth=10, color='tab:green', label='y')
plt.plot(predictions[:200], color='tab:red', linestyle='--', linewidth=1.8, label='prediction')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('index')
plt.ylabel('value')
```

Comment: Your result looks exactly what I need. Unfortunately, the code you provided generates a completely different [picture](https://imgur.com/a/iSP1NVl).

Comment: Not sure why that is. I sought to make the example reproducible by setting the random seed, so I expected to see identical results at your end. I'm using the latest version of python, sklearn, and xgboost. Try updating at least xgboost, and seeing whether that changes things.

Comment: I checked it in google colab and there the result is the same as yours. Fairy magic. I have python 3.8.10 and all libraries are up to date. Looks like I need to update my python version...

Comment: On Windows, it was not possible to get such a result. Already tried several versions of python.

Comment: I solved the problem. It turned out the whole thing was in the casting to int that you produced. On Windows, a Python's int is an int32, and on Linux, a Pythons int is an int64. The only flaw left in your answer is that you take all the data for training without allocating any dataset for the test.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem.